# My left click is not working in iMac

Tags: imac

I have an iMac that I bought in 2017.
Never give me issues, but suddenly the left click is not working.

I’m using a Logitech mouse, and I have tried changing the mouse to wired ones but the same issue persists.

Right click is working fine but left click is not

Requesting help on the resolution or at least the mitigation (how to activate hotkeys/etc) since right now my iMac is unusable. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean “doesn’t work?”  What is it (not) doing and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Can you check the System Preferences > Accessibility > Pointer Control, to see if alternative methods of clicking have been enabled?

Comment: does not work mean when I do left click, nothing is happening on the screen, only right click behaves as per normal. Expectation, is to see left click behaves normally E.g. can close the window..

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment, but not enough yet for an answer*

Two initial thoughts…

1- See if it works if you boot in Safe Mode. Hold the Shift key whilst booting.

2- See if enabling MouseKeys allows you to left-click in normal boot.

Press  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>F5</kbd> . This will pop up the Accessibility options without requiring you to use a mouse at all.
Use Tab to highlight Enable Mouse Keys & Spacebar to switch it on.

You can now navigate with just your keyboard.
If you have an extended keyboard, this is conveniently on the NumPad keys, like a compass around 5, which is your left click.
If you have a short keyboard, it's on 789,uio,jkl & i is your click.
[There's sometimes a slight oddity in behaviour… if you move the cursor with your real mouse, the 5 or i doesn't click properly - you have to make some slight movement using the keys before the click will register.]

Let us know if either of these works, & we can maybe investigate further.

Comment: Further context: I noticed that the after reboot, the left click works for about 10 minutes before stop working again. I also noticed that it looks like the MAC treat the last left click as if I never release the left click (e.g the mouse now stuck in a browser and I stuck dragging the browser here and there). I tried in the 10 minutes period where it's working to enable alternative key (press option 5 times for hotkeys), but I still can't use my keyboard to do it. (My keyboard is logitech, non-mac keyboard, don't know if this is the cause). Thanks